# Android Fragment Executing without being called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I have an app using Actionbar Sherlock that contains 3 tabs with their respective fragments.  When I login into the app, by default the Book Buy fragment is supposed to be executed.  What I notice is that after the Login is executed, the Sell fragment is partially executed. 
Here's the flow it's doing: Login -> Sell Frag -> Book Buy Frag -> Json Parser -> Sell Frag -> Json Parser -> Book Buy -> Custom Adapter.

The correct flow should be: Login -> Book Buy Frag -> Json Parser -> Book Buy -> Custom Adapter.

Needless to say it takes a while for me to get from Login to first screen.  Can anyone help me with this strange behavior? Keep in mind that no tab has been selected at this point.

Login Java:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

//TextView text;
ProgressDialog pDialog;

String uEmailLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_scrn);

    System.out.println("LoginActivity starte befoe session");

    //Declared the two variables as "final" for ICS compiler to recognize them in onClickListener
    final EditText userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailInpt);
    final EditText userPass  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInpt);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logError);
    Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    Button registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);

    //Executes this code when the submit button is pressed
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {         
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
         if(userEmail.getText().length()== 0) {
            text.setText("Enter Email Address");
            }
            else if(userPass.getText().length()== 0) {
             text.setText("Enter Password");
            }
            else {

                System.out.println("LogAct Check 2");
            //Start Async task here for Http...because 4.0 can't process data on main UI
                new CheckLogin().execute(userEmail.getText().toString(), 
                                         userPass.getText().toString());


                //Clears input data off phone screen after login button is hit
                userEmail.setText("");
                userPass.setText("");

                //finish();

                }
            }
         });    

      //original end of onClickListner
      //});

      // Link to Register Screen
      registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(register);
            finish();
        }
       });

    } 


//Class to check for successful Login
private class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //Progress Dialog
    //private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //Show Progress Dialog before starting background thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        System.out.println("LogAct onPreExecute started");
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this); //might can only be activity
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//might can only be activity
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        //System.out.println("onPreExecute finished");
    }

    //Get Login Info
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            JSONObject json_data = null;
            String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;

             //InputStream is = null;

             //Opens internet connection and prepares the files to be used in processing
             DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/bkbarter.php"); //emulator
             try{ 

                 //Loads the Array with the values to be sent to php code for db processing
                 ArrayList <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList                <NameValuePair>();
                 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAction", "login"));
                 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userEmail", arg0[0]));
                 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userPass", arg0[1]));

                 //Stores the user email to be later stored as a global variable in AsyncTask
                 uEmailLogin = arg0[0];

                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();

                 //Shows logcat status response to determine if data was sent correctly
                 //System.out.println("output = " + response);

                 Log.i("onClickListner", response.getStatusLine().toString());

                 //Clears input data off phone screen after login button is hit

                 } catch(Exception e){
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                 }

            //Converts the variables retrieved into a string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                String line = "0";

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    //System.out.println(sb);
                }

                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();
                System.out.println(result);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

            }

                    return result;
           }

//After completing background task, dismiss the progress dialog
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) { // might need to be (String result) here
    //super.onPostExecute(result);
    //JSONObject json_data = null;

    //dismiss the dialog after getting all the records
    if(pDialog != null) {
       pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            String success_resp_code = null;
            String error_resp_code = null;
            String userAction = null;

            //Parses the string to a JSON object 
            try {
                json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                //Stores the json response code
                success_resp_code = json_data.getString("success");
                error_resp_code = json_data.getString("error");
                userAction = json_data.getString("userAction");


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Login/JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            //Checks login status to for success or failure
            try {

                //if (json_data.getString("success") != null) {
                if (success_resp_code != null) {    

                    if(Integer.parseInt(success_resp_code) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //Calls Globals to set user Email as global variable
                        ((Globals) getApplicationContext()).setEmailLogin(uEmailLogin);

                        //Start BookBarter Activity
                           Intent bookBarter = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookBarterActivity.class);
                           startActivity(bookBarter);

                           //Close Login screen
                        //   finish();
                    }else if (json_data.getString("error") != null) {


                             if(Integer.parseInt(error_resp_code) == 1) {
                                 //User entered incorrect password
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

                             }else if(Integer.parseInt(error_resp_code) == 2) {
                                //User does not exist
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             }

                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

           }

          System.out.println("LogAct onPostExecute finished");
        }
    });

}
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(pDialog != null)
        pDialog.dismiss();
    pDialog = null;

    finish();
}

}
```

Book Buy Frag:

```
public class BuyFragTab extends SherlockListFragment {

//Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//Creating JSON Parser Object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//bookBuy JSON array
JSONArray bookBuyInfo = null;

//Array of book information 
ArrayList<Bookinfo> bookArray = new ArrayList<Bookinfo>();

//Book ListView
ListView bookLV;

MyCustomAdapter adapter;

//Search EditText
EditText titleSearch;

//DualPane variable
boolean mDualPane;
int mCurCheckPosition = 0;


//Holder array for json data movement
public static ArrayList<String> bkRecs;

Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_tbfrag, container, false);

    bookLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView bookLV
    bookLV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //Search inputed book title
    titleSearch = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.titleSearch);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //System.out.println("onActivityCreated executed");

    bookArray = new ArrayList<Bookinfo>();

    //Load bookArray in Background Thread
    new LoadBookBuyInfo().execute();

    View detailsFragment = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details_fragment_container);
    mDualPane = detailsFragment != null
           && detailsFragment.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;


    //Set up click listener for the item clicked in the ListView
    bookLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id){

        String selectTitle, selectAuthor, selectIsbn, selectCond, selectPrice = null;
        String selectSeller, selectEmail, selectPhone, selectCollege = null;

        //When item is clicked, show it's detailed view
        Bookinfo bkRecs = (Bookinfo)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);


        //Loads the Book Detail Information
        selectTitle = bkRecs.getTitle();
        ...loads data...

        System.out.println(" Title = " + selectTitle + " Author = " + selectAuthor);


        //If in Dual Pane/Landscape mode, send selected user information to Show Details to display 
        //to the screen
        if (mDualPane) {

            showDetails(selectTitle, selectAuthor, selectIsbn, selectCond, selectPrice,
                        selectSeller, selectEmail, selectPhone, selectCollege);
        }else { 

            //If in Portrait mode, create an intent object to start BookDetailsActivity     
            Intent bkIntent = new Intent("com.skipster.BookBarter.BOOKDETAILSACTIVITY");

            //Setting data (the clicked item's position to the intent
            bkIntent.putExtra("Selected_Title", selectTitle);
            ...put Extra data...

            //Start the activity
            startActivity(bkIntent);
         }
        }
    });


    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

}
//manages screen orientation flips********************************//
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}

//Landscap Mode screen processing
void showDetails(String Title, String Author, String Isbn, String Cond, String Price, String Seller,
                 String Email, String Phone, String College){

    //instantiating the fragment BookDetailsFragment
    SherlockFragment detailsFragment = new BookDetailsFragment();

    //get fragment manager for fragment related operations
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    //get fragment transaction object, which can add, move or replace a fragment
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    //creating a bundle object to pass the data (clicked item's position)
    //from this activity to fragment
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    //loading bundle object 
    b.putString("Selected_Title", Title);
    ...

    //setting/sending the bundle object to the fragment 
    //edited object is received and sent to be displayed
    detailsFragment.setArguments(b);
    System.out.println("Show Details check2");

    ft.replace(R.id.details_fragment_container, detailsFragment);
    System.out.println("Show Details check3");

    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

    //Allows for user to press back button to go back in reverse order
    //Works properly in landscape mode but not in portrait
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    //Executing the transaction
    ft.commit();
    return;
}

//Background AsyncTask to load all BookBuyInfo by making Http Request
class LoadBookBuyInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    //Show Progress Dialog before starting background thread
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//might can only be activity
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Books...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    //Get BookBuyInfo Data
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        //Building parameters
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> bookValues = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        System.out.println("doInBackground executed");
        //Loads user action to retrieve the book records
        bookValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAction", "GETR"));


        //getting JSON string from URL, "GETR" = get entire record
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2/bkbarter.php", "GETR", bookValues);       

        //Check logcat for JSON response
        Log.d("Book Buy JSON: ", json.toString());

        //Get JSON Data
        try {
            bookBuyInfo = json.getJSONArray("books");

            //loop through all books and load data
            for (int i = 0; i < bookBuyInfo.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject b = bookBuyInfo.getJSONObject(i);

                String seller = b.getString("Name");        
                ...book info...
                //creating new book record for bookArray
                Bookinfo bkRecs = new Bookinfo(title, author, isbn, cond, price,
                                               seller, email, phone, college);

                //Add record to arrayList
                bookArray.add(bkRecs);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    //After completing background task, dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { // might need to be (String result) here
        //dismiss the dialog after getting all the records
        //pDialog.dismiss();
        if(pDialog != null) {
           pDialog.dismiss();
        }
        //update UI from background thread
        //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.buy_tbfrag, bookArray);
                bookLV.setAdapter(adapter);

                //Enable Search filter to search titles as each letter is inputed
                titleSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable cs){
                        //TODO Auto generated method-stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int count, int after){
                        //TODO Auto generated method-stub
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int start, int before, int count){
                        //When user changed the text
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
                        System.out.println("onTextChanged executed");   
                    }

                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sell Frag:

```
public class SellFragTab extends SherlockFragment {

EditText sbkTitle, sbkAuthor, sbkISBN, sbkCond, sbkPhone, sbkPrice, sbkCollege;
    TextView text;

    //Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //bookBuy JSON array
    JSONArray bookBuyInfo = null;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        System.out.println("Sell Frag Tab executed");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sell_tbfrag, container, false);

        sbkTitle = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookTitle);
        sbkAuthor = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookAuthor);
        sbkISBN = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookISBN);
        sbkCond = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookCond);
        sbkPhone = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookPhone);
        sbkPrice = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookPrice);
        sbkCollege = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.sbookCollege);
        text       = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.regError);

        Button subButn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.subButn);

        System.out.println("Sell Frag Tab Check 2");
        subButn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (sbkTitle.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter Book Title");
                    } 
                else if (sbkAuthor.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter Book Author");
                    }
                else if (sbkCond.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter Book Condition");
                    }
                else if (sbkPhone.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter Phone Number");
                    }
                else if (sbkCollege.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter College Name");
                    }
                else if (sbkPrice.getText().length() == 0) {
                    text.setText("Enter Book Price");
                    }
                else {
                    //Gets the global uEmailLogin for comparison in the db.  This will allow the db to 
                    //be updated with book info if all they previously did was register.
                    String uEmailLogin = ((Globals) getActivity().getApplication()).getEmailLogin();

                    //Start Async task here for Http...because 4.0 can't process data on main UI
                    new PostBookInfo().execute(sbkTitle.getText().toString(), sbkAuthor.getText().toString(), 
                                             sbkISBN.getText().toString(), sbkCond.getText().toString(),
                                             sbkPhone.getText().toString(), sbkCollege.getText().toString(),
                                              sbkPrice.getText().toString(), uEmailLogin);

                    //Clears input data off phone screen after login button is hit
                    sbkTitle.setText("");
                    sbkAuthor.setText("");
                    sbkISBN.setText("");
                    sbkCond.setText("");
                    sbkPhone.setText("");
                    sbkCollege.setText("");
                    sbkPrice.setText("");
                    //finish();


                }
            }

        });

        return view;
    }

    //Background AsyncTask to load all BookBuyInfo by making Http Request
    class PostBookInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Show Progress Dialog before starting background thread
        //@Override
        //protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();

        //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//might can only be activity
        //  pDialog.setMessage("Selling...");
        //  pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //  pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //  pDialog.show();
        //}

        //Get BookBuyInfo Data
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            JSONObject json_data = null;
            String result = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            StringBuilder sb = null;

             //InputStream is = null;

             //Opens internet connection and prepares the files to be used in processing
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/bkbarter.php");
             try{ 

                 //Loads the Array with the values to be sent to php code for db processing
                 ArrayList <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                 nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userAction", "postr"));
                         ...load data...                 

                 System.out.println("nvps = " + nvps);
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                 is = entity.getContent();

                 //Shows logcat status response to determine if data was sent correctly
                 Log.i("onClickListner", response.getStatusLine().toString());


                 } catch(Exception e){
                   Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                 }

            //Converts the variables retrieved into a string
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

                String line = "0";

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    System.out.println(sb);
                }

                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

            }
            return(result);
    }

    //After completing background task, dismiss the progress dialog
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) { // might need to be (String result) here
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                String success_resp_code = null;
                String error_resp_code = null;
                String userAction = null;


            //Parses the string to a JSON object 
            try {
                json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                success_resp_code = json_data.getString("success");
                error_resp_code = json_data.getString("error");
                userAction = json_data.getString("userAction");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Register/JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            //Checks register status to for success or failure
            try {

                if (json_data.getString("success") != null &&
                          Integer.parseInt(success_resp_code) == 1){

                    //Successful save of book information
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Book info has been saved",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else if(json_data.getString("error") != null &&
                               Integer.parseInt(error_resp_code) == 1) {

                        //Unsuccessful saving book information
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error saving book info",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 

           }
           }
     });
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actionbar Sherlock sometimes also loads the tab left and right of the current one in order to allow fast change of tabs. I had this problem in another project: try to leave out code in the onCreate that you do not want to be executed.